# Table headers are not loaded when loading CSV file using langchain UnstructuredCSVLoader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, langchain

I am trying to load a CSV file using langchain UnstructuredCSVLoader, but when I print the doc I am not able to see the table headers.

I tried UnstructuredExcelLoader as well but facing similar issue, CSVLoader is able to load headers but it loads individual rows as separate docs which is not helpful in my case.

This is how I am loading the file:

```
loader = UnstructuredCSVLoader("sample.csv", mode="elements")
docs = loader.load()
```